# Unable to translate Unicode character \\uDCC9 at index 5 to specified code page

Tags: mariadb, unicode, mariadb-10.2

I'm using MariaDB (and Adminer)

> MySQL version: 5.5.5-10.10.2-MariaDB-1:10.10.2+maria~ubu2204 through PHP extension MySQLi

And this is the `show create table Pages`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Pages` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Guid` uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `Name` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `AcceptsComment` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `Key` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `IsVital` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Slug` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Pages_Unique_Guid` (`Guid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Pages_Unique_Key` (`Key`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Pages_Unique_Slug` (`Slug`),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Pages_NonEmptyGuid` CHECK (`Guid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

I'm using [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) to insert some fake data using `MySqlBulkCopy`. But when I call `bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table)`, I get this error:

> Unable to translate Unicode character \uDCC9 at index 5 to specified code page.

I realized that [\uDCC9](https://charbase.com/dcc9-unicode-invalid-character) is a � character.

However, I use UTF for all of my columns.

I can't understand why this happens. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Surrogates" are not handled in utf8mb3; you need utf8mb4.

```
ALTER TABLE pages CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
                  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;`
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Does it make the databse slower? What could be downsides for utf8mbf?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati - Not enough slower to worry about.  Anyway, if you need Emoji and all of the Chinese characters, you need utf8mb4.  With the thing that comes after \uDCC9, we could figure out what "character" was desired.